# Blazor SQL query insert to table based on SQL query

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, t-sql, blazor

I'm new and just learning Blazor. I'm using Entity Framework Core library. While I managed to extract data from the SQL Server table, I already have a problem with Insert.

It is not an ordinary insert (fetching data from a form), but based on a SQL query. I only need one field where I enter the index and the query checks whether there is such an index in the database and takes the entire row on the basis and throws it into the database.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 1  
    tk.Twr_Kod,Twr_Nazwa, tk.Twr_Jm, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Twr_GIDNumer IN (SELECT DISTINCT TwP_TwrNumer
                              FROM [ERPXL_VIKKING].CDN.TwrPodm
                              WHERE TwP_Warstwa = 0)
            THEN 1
        WHEN Twr_GIDNumer IN (SELECT DISTINCT TwP_ZamNumer
                              FROM [ERPXL_VIKKING].CDN.TwrPodm
                              WHERE TwP_Warstwa <> 0)
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
    END AS CzyMaZmienniki,
    GETDATE() AS DATA, 
    Twr_GidNumer AS gid_towar
FROM  
    [ERPXL_VIKKING].CDN.TwrKarty tk
WHERE 
    tk.Twr_Typ = 1 
    AND Twr_Kod =??variable
```

I have a service class where I contain all actions.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Balzor3000.Data;

namespace Balzor3000.Data
{
    public class okuciaServices
    {
        private readonly testdbcontext _testdbcontext;

        public okuciaServices(testdbcontext Testdbcontext)
        {
            _testdbcontext = Testdbcontext;
        }

        //pobierz okucia
        public async Task<List<okucia_magazyn>> PobierzWszystko()
        {
            return await _testdbcontext.okucia_Magazyn.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }
        //Dodaj okucie

        // public async Task<List<okucia_magazyn>> Dodajelement
        public async Task<bool> Dodajokucie(okucia_magazyn magazyn)
        {
             await _testdbcontext.okucia_Magazyn.AddAsync(magazyn);
            
             await _testdbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
             return true;
        }

        //pobierz okucie
        public async Task<okucia_magazyn> Pobierzokucie(int id)
        {
            okucia_magazyn m =  await _testdbcontext.okucia_Magazyn.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
            return m;
        }

        //Update
        public async Task<bool> Updateokucia(okucia_magazyn okucia)
        {
            _testdbcontext.okucia_Magazyn.Update(okucia);
            await _testdbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }

        //Delete
        public async Task<bool> usunOkucia(okucia_magazyn okucia)
        {
            _testdbcontext.okucia_Magazyn.Remove(okucia);
            await _testdbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Only method

```
public async Task<okucia_magazyn> Pobierzokucie(int id)
```

will add everything and I need to add based on SQL query.

Does anyone have a tutorial or guidance?

I tried to look for something on the internet.

Comment: Not clear on what the issue is. Are you getting an Exception or error?

Comment: If you want to use vanilla SQL, don't use EF.  Use Dapper, and just do normal SQL calls.

Comment: thanks for the tip with this dapper. It helped me a lot.

Comment: yes agree, do normal SQL calls --> might be better for custom & complex logic